# How do I group two time interval columns into discernible months?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, time

I have a housing market dataset categorized by U.S Counties showing columns such as total_homes_sold. I'm trying to show a comparison between housing sales YoY (e.g. Jan 2020 vs. Jan 2019) and by county (e.g. Aberdeen Mar 2020 vs. Suffolk Mar 2020). However not sure how to group the dates as they are not sorted by months (Jan, Feb, Mar etc.) but rather by 4-week intervals: period_begin and period_end.

Intervals between years vary. The period_begin for Aberdeen (around Jan) for 2019 might be 1/7 to 2/3 but 1/6 to 2/2 for 2020 (image shown below).

I tried using **count** (code below) to label each 4-week period as a number (shown below) thinking I could compare Aberdeen 2017-1 to Aberdeen 2020-1 (1 coded as the first time interval) but realized that some years for some regions have more 4 week periods in a year than others (2017 has 13 whereas 2018 has 14).

```
*df['count'] = df.groupby((everyfourth['region_name'] != df['region_name'].shift(1)).cumsum()).cumcount()+1*
```

Any ideas on what code I could use to closely categorize these two columns into month-like periods?

[Snippet of Dataset here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBT5f.png)

Let me know if you have any questions. Not sure I made sense! Thanks.